# SIM contacts are shown in Messaging application, but not displayed in Contacts list

Tags: contacts, sms, sim-card

I changed the option to only see my Google contacts (GMail) (and hide my SIM contacts).
This is working perfectly in the "Contacts" app, but when I try to send a text message, and I provide a keyword in the "To" field, all my SIM contacts appear as well.

Is there another possibility to hide the SIM contacts, except removing the numbers on the SIM card?

Thanks!
Jochen

ps: I'm using 4.1.2 (Jellybean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the Messaging app has its own Contacts app, with no way to configure it.

How about using 3rd party alternatives? I use GO SMS Pro as replacement for the Messaging app, and Go Contacts Ex as replacement for the Contacts app. With this combination, you can hide the SIM contacts.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by 
Contacts >groups >not assigned. 
You can choose what to do with them from there. This is the only way I've found to delete contacts that show up in messenger and not in any other place.